# (Unity) Better to copy a component many times or to make it a public static?

Tags: unity-game-engine, static, singleton, components, public

I found this code to have objects sort themselves based on Y Position, but I am having to copy the script with the code onto basically everything on my map. Would it be better, for CPU and/or memory, to make the method a singleton and put it in everybody's Update?

Here is the sorting function:

```
public class SortOrder : MonoBehaviour {

void Update () {
    GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sortingOrder =
    Mathf.RoundToInt(transform.position.y * 100f) * -1;
    }
}
```

But I could make it like:

```
public static void SortOrder(){
    GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sortingOrder =
    Mathf.RoundToInt(transform.position.y * 100f) * -1;
}
```

And just put it in Update functions where I need it.

Is there any difference between these options in terms of CPU or memory load?

Answer (score 3):

Another option would be to make an extension method. That way you just set the sorting order of the SpriteRenderer, by the Transform you pass in.

```
public static class SpriteRendererExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Set the SpriteRenderer sorting order by the Transform.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sr">The SpriteRenderer being extended.</param>
    /// <param name="transform">The Transform of the object to use for sorting.</param>
    public static void SetSortingOrder ( this SpriteRenderer sr, Transform transform )
    {
        sr.sortingOrder = Mathf.RoundToInt ( transform.position.y * 100f ) * -1;
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
    GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ( ).SetSortingOrder(this.transform);
```

Or you could even save the reference, and use the Inspector:

```
public SpriteRenderer sr;
// ...
sr.SetSortingOrder(this.transform);
```

Answer (score 2):

For CPU performance, it's always best to have one update loop which does similar jobs all at once one the same dataset. You can achieve this by eg creating a tag for all sprites that need auto-ordering based on transform position. Then have one 'controller' component which loops over these SpriteRenderer components each frame:

```
public class SpriteSorting : MonoBehaviour {
    public string sortingTag;

    List<SpriteRenderer> spritesNeedingSorting = new List<SpriteRenderer> ();

    void Start () {
        var gameObjects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag (sortingTag);
        foreach (var gameObject in gameObjects) {
            spritesNeedingSorting.Add (gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ());
        }
    }

    void Update () {
        foreach (var sprite in spritesNeedingSorting) {
            sprite.sortingOrder = Mathf.RoundToInt (sprite.transform.position.y * 100f) * -1f;
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously, if you need to spawn and destroy sprites dynamically, you will need to make this component into a singleton and implement functions for adding and removing components from the list and call these explicitly.